# How to resume execution of playbook from same place where it failed?

Tags: ansible, angular6

I am running a playbook for deployment of nodes.Suppose because of some issue like power failure or some other exception, the execution failed after executing some tasks.So, I am trying to resume the execution from same place where it failed, when I run the playbook next time.

It is time consuming to run the playbook for all the task from start.Is it possible to achieve the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function --start-at-task="task name" this will run the whole playbook from the specific task name and continue from there om. But be careful, if you have registered any variables in tasks before and use them afterwards, starting at that task will not register them and therefore the play will not use them. In that case you could give tag "always" to the tasks that register variables

Answer (score 0):

The output of a failed ansible-playbook run actually tells you how to do this (assuming you have 'retry_files_enabled' set true in your config, which is the default):

> to retry, use: --limit @/some/path/to/a/retry/file

In the case of a failure, Ansible will create a retry file, which is for the specific purpose of what you requested. Therefore, just append the '--limit' statement to the command you used to run the playbook and kick it off again.

Edit: To be fair, your specific case of a power failure on the control machine would not be covered by this, but any failure that Ansible handles (i.e. the majority), will work with this method.

Answer (score 0):

execute like this:

```
ansible-playbook --forks=10 myscript.yml --start-at-task='install java'
```

with limit: `ansible-playbook --forks=10 myscript.yml --limit limit1 --start-at-task='install java'`